# Indentation of blocks within case statements in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get vim to play nicely with [GTK's coding style](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/plain/docs/CODING-STYLE) by setting cinoptions but I can't figure out what to use for case statements.

Desired:

```
switch (x)
  {
  case 1:
    {
      foo();
    }
  case 2:
    bar();
  }
```

A) What I get with (not desired): setlocal et sw=2 cinoptions=>4,n-2,{2

```
switch (x)
  {
  case 1:
      {
        foo();
      }
  case 2:
    bar();
  }
```

B) What I get with (not desired): setlocal et sw=2 cinoptions=>4,n-2,{2,=0

```
switch (x)
  {
  case 1:
    {
      foo();
    }
  case 2:
  bar();
  }
```

Is there a way of getting the desired indentation automatically?

Answer (score 3):

From the vim `:help cino-:`

> ```
>                       *cino-:*
>     :N    Place case labels N characters from the indent of the switch().
>           (default 'shiftwidth').
>
>         cino=                 cino=:0
>             switch (x)            switch(x)
>             {                     {
>                case 1:            case 1:
>                   a = b;             a = b;
>                default:           default:
>             }                     }
>
>                                                    *cino-=*
>     =N    Place statements occurring after a case label N characters from
>           the indent of the label.  (default 'shiftwidth').
>
>             cino=                 cino==10 >
>                case 11:             case 11:  a = a + 1;
>                    a = a + 1;                 b = b + 1;
> ```

You need add `:0` to your `cinoptions`.

If need to also set `=3` if you want `3` characters of indent under `case`.

Comment: Well I set :2 to have the case indented two spaces from the switch, and =2 to have the statements after the case label indented two spaces from the label, but that gives the same result as (A), above.

Comment: @RossLagerwall, checkut `help :cino-f` and `help : cinfo-{`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. cino-f seems to be specifically for the indent of top-level functions which doesn't help, and I'm already setting {2 in the examples above so that braces are indented by 2.